# Hospital route finding ai project

Tags: search, mapping, path-finding, a-star

so in an intro to AI course we where given a project to find the optimal route using search algorithms to a relevant hospital in a certain city, and we are asked to consider the map of the hospitals in this city, i have a problem of how to select the initial state it sure is the patient localization but how can i incorporate it into my search graph which is the map of hospitals dynamically (im thinking that localization is in long/lat format)

i thought of a dynamic graph but i can't see how can i incorporate  the patient localization dynamically